# Transforming large image into Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've looked at http://code.google.com/p/maptiler/ and http://www.bartlett.ucl.ac.uk/casa/latest/software/gmap-image-cutter

Maptiler won't generate a gmaps for a png with no geodata (just need to be able to refer to stuff as x,y pixel coords -> latlng), raster only has openlayers. Openlayers/etc isn't an option for me.

Gmap image cutter plain dies when I attempt to open a 2GB image.

Are there any other suggestions or any way I can get tiles working on Gmap v3?

Answer (score 1):

I've personally had a lot more luck with Photoshop scripts when cutting tiles. Here's a relatively new one (but one I haven't used myself): http://www.bram.us/2012/04/23/photoshop-google-maps-tile-cutter-script/